# Sync Windows sticky notes to Gmail

Tags: windows, sync, gmail, google-sync, sticky-notes

I have an **iPad**, with **notes** set to "**Gmail**", so, when I go on **Gmail.com**, they are all there.

I want the "**Sticky Notes**" from my **Windows 10** Computer to **sync** the same way.

**How** can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this and see if it helps: http://www.technorms.com/33960/sync-windows-sticky-notes-across-computers

Basically, you're setting up a link in Google Drive to your Sticky Notes directory on your machine.  You then just need to follow the instructions on your other machine to get access to them.

Alternatively, if you use the Google version [Google Keep], this will be synced with all your machines that use Google Chrome & any Android devices that you use (you would just need to download the Google Keep app)

HTH

Comment: That's cool.  If you found this answer helpful, i'd appreciate an up-vote or 'tick'. :)